# How to get Sharepoint ListItem on DriveItem with Microsoft Graph API c# SDK

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

`ListItem` of a `driveItem` is in a document library is always `null`. How to get custom fields of file? I want to build a function to get the content stream and fields of file.

```cs
var client = GetAuthenticatedClient();
var driveItems = await client.Sites[siteId].Drives[driveId].Root.Children.Request().GetAsync();
foreach (var driveItem in driveItems)
{
    //ListItem is always null
    if (driveItem.ListItem!=null)
    {
        //get columns
        var blabla = driveItem.ListItem.Fields.AdditionalData["blabla"];
    }

    //SharepointIds is always null too 
    if (driveItem.SharepointIds != null)
    {

    }

    //get file to download
    var file = await client.Drives[driveId].Items[driveItem.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add ListItem explicitly to DriveItem

```csharp
var driveItems = await client.Sites[siteId].Drives[driveId].Root.Children.Request().Expand(item => item.ListItem).GetAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sharepointIds` property of the drive item should contain the information you need to read the list item.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepointids?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: As i wrote it in my sample code, SharepointIds property is always null too...

Comment: @J.Y.  You need to explicitly Select the SharepointIds property for it to be returned.